# Adding userId to a post request node express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, lodash

I have a node application whwere I create a post and I have to pass the person who created the posts ID as well as the post. The issue is I have always written everything out like this

```
const imageUrl = req.file.path;
const title = req.body.title;
const content = req.body.content;
const post = new Post({
  title: title,
  content: content,
  imageUrl: imageUrl,
  creator: req.userId
});
```

my question now is if I have a lot of these, is it not possible to use a library like lodash to pick out all the field like

```
const body = _.pick(req.body, ['produtTitle', 'productImg', 'productPrice', 'productDesc'])
    console.log(`THIS IS ${body}`)
    const product = new Product({
      body,
      userId: req.userId
    });
```

Everytime I try it like that, I get 404 and in my teminal I get

> message: 'Path `productPrice` is required.',
>           name: 'ValidatorError',
>           properties: [Object],
>           kind: 'required',
>           path: 'productPrice',
>           value: undefined,
>           reason: undefined,
>           '$isValidatorError': true },

for all the fields

and if I do it likethis `const product = new Product(req.body)`, I get just one error for the 404

```
message: 'Path `userId` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'userId',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        '$isValidatorError': true } }
```

I am looking at a library because writing everything out could be very tedious and in a case where there are a lot of field required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lodash but you are passing body as a key when creating new product. You need to spread the keys of the body.

```
const body = _.pick(req.body, ['produtTitle', 'productImg', 'productPrice', 'productDesc'])

    const product = new Product({
      ...body,
      userId: req.userId
    });
```